# Paginator does not work

Tags: python, django, pagination

Paginator does not work.I wrote views.py

```
from .models import POST
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render

def top(request):
    item = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    page = _get_page(item, request.GET.get('page'))
    return render(request, 'top.html',{'item':item,"page":page})

def _get_page(list_, page_no, count=1):
    paginator = Paginator(list_, count)
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_no)
    except (EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger):
        page = paginator.page(1)
    return page
```

in top.html

```
<div>
         {% for i in item %}
            <div>
                 <h2>{{ i.title }}</h2>
                 <p>{{ i.index }}</p>
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
    </div>

   <div>
       {% if page.has_previous %}
          <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
       {% endif %}

       {% for num in page.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if page.number == num %}
             <span>{{ num }}</span>
          {% else %}
             <a href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
          {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}

       {% if page.has_next %}
          <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
       {% endif %}
   </div>
```

When I access top.html,all item is shown in browser.I think I wrote one item was shown in one page(browser) in this part page = paginator.page(page_no) ,but no error happens so I really cannot understand  what is wrong.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your for loop - `{% for i in item %}`. You are looping over the `item` object. Whereas you need to loop over the `page` object like - `{% for i in page %}`

Answer (score 0):

Your view sets `item` to *all* objects stored in the `POST` model and passes them to the template. The template then iterates over the `item` list and therefore will display all objects without pagination.

`page` is a single page of objects, and that is what your template should iterate over.

Also there does not appear to be a reason for passing `item`, i.e. all of the `POST` objects, to the template because it is not being used. Probably best to remove it.